# Valor da variavel do typescript dentro do css do componente

Tags: angular

tem alguma forma no angular de eu usar um valor de uma variavel que está no ts do meu componente lá dentro do css desse componente, por que preciso usar uma cor no css que está vindo do banco de dados... e essa cor fica disponivel no ts do componente, tem alguma forma de usar esse valor dessa cor lá dentro do css do componente ?

Comment: Utilize no próprio arquivo .ts
Procure sobre alterar css no próprio js.

Comment: Poste seu código, coloque detalhes do que precisa.